# Ansible debug permissions of ansible scripts

Tags: linux, permissions, ansible

I have a user AAA, and set my remote path (successfully) to /home/AAA/.ansible_tmp/, and ansible successfully ssh'ed into the box with AAA, and I still get permission denied on the python scripts of ansible itself.

This seems rather strange, to me, and I'm trying to debug with -vvv, but to no avail.

Can I somehow check the file permissions of the remote ansible scripts?

Comment: Can you start by giving a minimum of information on your problem? create a minimal ansible playbook and inventory reproducing your problem, paste them in your question and show a full debug run (-vvv) of that playbook using the inventory.

Comment: Already Solved, turned out fapolicyd prevented me from executing any (untrusted) scripts. Adding a rule fixed it. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question; turns out the problem had nothing to do with Ansible itself. During installation, I had selected the "ACSC Essential Eight" security policy, which configured fapolicyd to prevent the execution of untrusted scripts.By allowing execution in my home dir, I was able to resolve the issue.